# Generate a chm file from a html directory

Tags: windows, chm

I'm looking for a Windows tool to generate a chm file from a bunch of HTML files... any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [HTML Help Workshop](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=00535334-c8a6-452f-9aa0-d597d16580cc) and some [associated docs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/orkXP/CH011495251033.aspx).